# Why Special characters like &, + are replaced in http request

Tags: jsp, encoding, httprequest, decoding

```
<form action="param.jsp">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select languages that you have worked with:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="languages" size="7"  id="lang" multiple="multiple" onchange="validateSelection();">
                    <option value="Ada">Ada</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="C++">C++</option>
                    <option value="Sun&">C++</option>
                    <option value="cobol$">Cobol</option>
                    <option value="java%">java</option>
                    <option value="php)">Php</option>
                    <option value="Objective-C">Objective-C</option>
                    <option value=".net">.Net</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Finish survey"/></p>
    </form>
```

As you can see it is simple form, my question is 
when I was trying to get c++ , Sun& , cobol$ values in my param.jsp
I have noticed that in address bar of a browser with http request, the parameters values such as C++ was replaced as C%2B%2B and
Sun& was replaced as Sun%26
please let me know why this is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the link
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

The characters to be specified in the url are limited. Also see the url specification.